# Append values to a dictionary with automatic key

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I am looking for a way to append a list in a dictionary whereas the key of the dictionary are simply automatically enumerated numbers as 1, 2, 3 etc.

So I have tried a lot of methods, the last one being enumerated, having :

```py
T = dict()
for index, K in enumerate(tab):   
     OrderVertices(K, oG)
     if K in T.values():
         pass
     else:
         T[index].append(K)
         print(T)
```

The error is in this line

```
T[index].append(K)
```

I don't know how to express it correctly.

tab being a 2d list as : [[2, 1, 4], [1, 3, 5]], and OrderVertices a function which sorts K accordingly to oG, working correctly

I am looking forward to get a dictionary like that :

```
{
 1: [2, 1, 4], 
 2: [1, 3, 5]
}
```

without changing the structure of the code and the index number automatically arrange themselves accordingly to how much elements there is with K

If someone could guide me please,

Thank you all

Comment: `T[index].append(K)` will only work if `T[index]` already contains a list. This is why we have [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Are you sure you don't just want `T[index] = K`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to emulate the behaviour of... a list ;) Just use a list and `append`. If you really need indexing to start on 1, add an initial dummy element.